# Web Scraping Table with class from CoinMarketCap w

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an entire table of data from:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/

I'm trying to extract the table:

```
<table class="h7vnx2-2 jNaLNi cmc-table ">
```

with

```
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"h7nvx2-2 jNaLNi cmc-table"})
```

and it returns: None

here's the full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/"
    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table', {"class":"h7nvx2-2 jNaLNi cmc-table"})
    print(table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to find historical data for Etherium if so it is dynamic generated

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the data is dynamically rendered. Go to the api to get the data directly:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url ='https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/historical'
payload = {
   'id':'1027',
   'convertId':'2781',
   'timeStart':'1623283200',
   'timeEnd':'1628553600' }

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData, record_path=['data','quotes'])

#rows = [i['quote'] for i in jsonData['data']['quotes']]
#df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
           open         high  ...     marketCap                 timestamp
0   2611.142652  2619.957793  ...  2.872870e+11  2021-06-10T23:59:59.999Z
1   2472.858836  2495.414705  ...  2.736314e+11  2021-06-11T23:59:59.999Z
2   2354.752218  2447.227868  ...  2.758389e+11  2021-06-12T23:59:59.999Z
3   2372.690096  2547.367910  ...  2.916739e+11  2021-06-13T23:59:59.999Z
4   2508.770462  2606.432929  ...  2.951126e+11  2021-06-14T23:59:59.999Z
..          ...          ...  ...           ...                       ...
56  2725.669632  2840.430748  ...  3.307572e+11  2021-08-05T23:59:59.999Z
57  2827.503486  2944.903352  ...  3.382378e+11  2021-08-06T23:59:59.999Z
58  2891.707469  3170.229727  ...  3.694372e+11  2021-08-07T23:59:59.999Z
59  3161.232779  3184.603971  ...  3.526859e+11  2021-08-08T23:59:59.999Z
60  3012.885711  3185.701187  ...  3.707654e+11  2021-08-09T23:59:59.999Z

[61 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: looping over rows to construct a DataFrame is unlikely usage due to performance.

Comment: changed to utilize `.json_normalize()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlencode


def main(url):
    params = {
        'id': '1027',
        'convertId': '2781',
        'timeStart': '1623283200',
        'timeEnd': '1628553600'
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(
        url + urlencode(params))['data']['quotes'])
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['quote'])
    print(df)


main('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/historical?')
```